# Android: Do I open a file resource everytime I want to log

Tags: java, android, file-io

I am doing my own logger in android by writing to a file. Currently, I call function that opens a file and appends a string to it. However, i read somewhere that it is exccessive ( operation heavy) to open a file everytime  I log to it. Is this true? What's the alternative here? Should I open a file a leave it open for the duration of the app and just append to it? Or what do you suggest?

Thank you very much

Comment: Yes, it could be heavy operation as you may be logging every few milli or micro seconds. I have few options 1) Keep the file open and keep writing 2) Have a Buffer where you can log your messages temporarily and flush the message at once to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how much logging you're doing - How many logs a second, roughly how much data, how critical the logs are, etc.  If you're only dropping something into the file a couple times a minute, than as long as it's not happening on the main thread and slowing other stuff down, you're probably fine.  If you do need to implement something more efficient, you might want to try some simple caching.

You could keep an in-memory cache of log data and save it to the file when it reaches a certain size (every 100 lines) or when a certain amount of time passes (every 5 minutes).

If you take this approach, remember to override onPause and onDestroy and make sure to write cached log data out to file before leaving the app, in case the user doesn't come back.

Comment: Hmm makes sense. I am logging alot so I guess our option of caching and writing it is good. However now I need to figure out when to write it. As I want this file to be sent over when a crash happens. And I can't predict when a crash happens. Maybe leaving the file open will makes more sense

Comment: I Use ACRA. I dont want only the crash reports, I need my logs to see what conditions led to such crash.